# How do you move a complete eclipse (3.x) tab folder of views?

Tags: eclipse

It has always been obvious to me how I could move around a single view (e.g. Console) in eclipse: just drag the view's tab around. However, when switching monitor configurations, I often want to move the entire tab folder of views, not just one view from the folder.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

Grab the tab folder in the tab bar area, but to the right of all the tabs.

It seems obvious now, but it took me a long time to figure this out. I couldn't find the answer via google or stackoverflow searches, even after multiple attempts. Hopefully this saves somebody else's time.